# Customizing build tool for unsupported languages

Tags: gradle, build

I'm trying to adopt a new build tool, for a language that isn't supported by any build tool (that I've Googled). I don't really need fancy features from the build tool.

I've tried using Gradle, but couldn't find examples/tutorials on writing plugins to support new languages.

Can any one recommend a build tool, that easily supports adding new languages, and has good documentation or examples of how to do it?

Comment: Should be rather easy to make a Gradle task that calls your language compiler. Just look at the userguide on how to write custom tasks and plugins. Unfortunately "recommend a tool" questions are off-topic on SO. But if you have touble while creating your Gradle task or plugin, feel free to open a new question with your specific problem.

Comment: Of course there are no such examples, because you would need to implement compilation for the language. No one will do that for you. That said, you can look into Kotlin plugin source and find how they did that.