# Customizing gradle for unsupported language

Tags: gradle

I want to add support in Gradle for a new language.

In order to compile a single file (with explicit file name), I can do something like this:

```
task compileVCSVlog(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'vlogan', 'somefile.v'
}
```

But that's of course not good. I'd like to have some iteration over a list of source files.

I assume Gradle has some built in mechanism, that defines the expected `src` directory name, and make some list of files in it with specific extension (or maybe only those that are needed for an incremental compilation).

Looking at the documentation, I've found `sourceSets`, which seems to be Java-specific, and things like `CSourceSet`, `CppSourceSet`, etc. , which of course, are specific for their languages.

There is a `LanguageSourceSet` in the JavaDoc, but it seems too obfuscated for me. Is it really what I need? How should it be used? Maybe some usage example?

## EDIT

I've come across [working with files doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html). Is that the preferred way of compiling list of files? Should it be combined with `LanguageSourceSet`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customizing build tool for unsupported languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44673327/customizing-build-tool-for-unsupported-languages)

Comment: If your compiler is written in Java, add it to the classpath and create a task of type `JavaExec`. If it is a commandline tool create a task of type `Exec`. You should read more than one paragraph in the user guide and the DSL doc and JavaDoc and come back here if you have concrete problems. Your question is still too broad to not being off-topic and actually almost a duplicate of your other question.